# Why does FFMPEG adds up extra bit rate to video?

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate

I use FFMPEG (command line Input) to convert my videos to a specific output format. The problem I am facing is when I  try to pass a constant bit rate(700 kbps) to FFMPEG, the result is an output video with a different bit rate(say 1000 kbps). This phenomenon occurs invariably for all videos.Why is this happening? I need to maintain a constant bit rate. Can anyone help me out.

My FFMPEG version is 0.5

The command line parameter which I am passing to FFMPEG is,

```
-i {inputfile}
-b 700k -ab 64k
-vcodec libx264
-acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 44100
-y -s 320x240 
{outputfile}
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to force CBR with a fluctuation of +/- 3% when I used the following parameters.

```
 ffmpeg -i myfile.avi
 -b 4000k -minrate 4000k 
 -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 1835k   out.m2v
```

But when I used -maxrate and - minrate along with my parameter set I was not able to force CBR. My parameter set is as follows,

```
-i {inputfile}
-b 1200k -minrate 1200k 
 -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 1200k 
-ab 64k -vcodec libx264
-acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 44100
-y -s 320x240 
{outputfile}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't forget that your audio bitrate is adding 64 kbps.

Comment: I thought the `-b` switch has been deprecated.

Comment: @Marco well it's not deprecated, but it does have a different meaning than it used to: `-b` used to set video bit rate, but *now* it sets the overall bit rate (both video & audio). To set the video bitrate, you should more properly use `-b:v` (and `-b:a` instead of `-ab`). None of this will particularly help the questioner, though.

Answer (score 1):

To force a CBR you should use `minrate`, `maxrate` and `bufsize` (see [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html))

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi
       -b 4000k -minrate 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 1835k
       out.m2v
```